# C# - Get public key from PDF Signature

Tags: c#, pdf, ssl, certificate

The use case is as follows:

1. User enter to a website that requires to present a certificate
2. If valid, the user can download a PDF and sign it with the same certificate
3. Uploads the PDF
4. Server validates PDF is signed by the same certificate that presents to the website.

I'm stuck at step 4. I have managed to get the client certificate public key from the website and also from the PDF, but are not the same. The public key is an SHA256 RSA of 2048 bits. Also, I'm using iTextSharp to handle PDF documents.

Here is my code:

```
 HttpRequest request = context.Request;

 HttpClientCertificate cert = request.ClientCertificate;

 //get public key from client certificate
 string certKey = BitConverter.ToString(cert.PublicKey).Replace("-", " ")

 //now gets PDF and retrieves public key
 PdfReader pdfreader = new PdfReader("path_to_pdf");


 AcroFields fields = pdfreader.AcroFields;
 AcroFields.Item item = fields.GetFieldItem("Signature1");
 List<string> names = fields.GetSignatureNames();

 foreach (string name in names){
     PdfDictionary dict = fields.GetSignatureDictionary(name);
     PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = fields.VerifySignature(name);
     Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert = pkcs7.SigningCertificate;

     //get public key from PDF cert
     SubjectPublicKeyInfo publicKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(cert.GetPublicKey());
     byte[] serializedPublicBytes = publicKeyInfo.ToAsn1Object().GetDerEncoded();
     string serializedPublic = BitConverter.ToString(serializedPublicBytes).Replace("-", " ");
 }
```

With this code certKey and serializedPublic are not the same.

Comment: are they fundamentally different (regarding length and overall similarity of parts of the byte sequence), or maybe just a DER/base64 encoding mismatch? Also, when you look at both certificates using the operating system's or PDF viewer's certificate property dialogs, do those match?

Comment: I have not though of that. My code is getting from the PDF the same as I can see directly from viewer's certificate property and is not the same from the certificate

Comment: I would not suspect the browser/iis roundtrip to mess with [the public key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpclientcertificate.publickey(v=vs.110).aspx)... then we should try to find out where the difference becomes apparent first. I suppose you have some kind of self-signed certificate for testing? does the public key as it appears in the signed PDF match the original certificate's in first place?

Comment: @A77ak You appear to compare the public key binary value from the certificate (`HttpClientCertificate.PublicKey`) with the binary value of a `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` object (`publicKeyInfo.ToAsn1Object().GetDerEncoded()`) *which wraps the public key and its algorithm*. The latter, therefore, might be expected to contain the former but not to coincide with it. You may want to try `publicKeyInfo.PublicKeyData.GetBytes()` instead

Comment: @mkl it works! Thank you

Comment: Ok, I'll make that an actual answer you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you compare

- the public key binary value from the certificate (`HttpClientCertificate.PublicKey`) with
- the binary value of a `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` object (`publicKeyInfo.ToAsn1Object().GetDerEncoded()`) which wraps the public key and its algorithm.

The latter, therefore, might be expected to *contain* the former but *not to coincide* with it.

A `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` is defined like this:

```
SubjectPublicKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
    algorithm AlgorithmIdentifier,
    publicKey BIT STRING
}
```

Instead of comparing with the binary representation of the full `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` object, therefore, you should compare with the binary representation of the contained public key:

```
publicKeyInfo.PublicKeyData.GetBytes()
```